# UIRefreshControl not working for UITableView in popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad, uirefreshcontrol

My app has two viewControllers containing UITableViews. One viewController is displayed as a custom fullscreen view inside the app, the other one is displayed as an popover view. I added an UIRefreshControl to both tableViews in order to update their content. Dragging the refreshControl and refreshing the tableView works fine for the custom fullscreen view. However, the popover view's refreshControl does not seem to work. When I drag down inside the tableView, the refreshControl's activity indicator progresses but stops at 11/12 (as seen in the image below) and the regfresh action will not be called.

[image: Activity indicator will stop at 11/12]

The initialization code for the popover's refreshControl is identical with the working refreshControl (except the action's names are different):

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"Refreshing..."];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget: self action: @selector(reloadTableData) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableView addSubview: self.refreshControl];
}

- (void) reloadTableData
{
    // reloading code. This method is not called in the popover view
}
```

I have struggled with this problem for a while now but did not manage to find any solutions. Could it be that the placing a refreshControl inside a popover view causes erroneous behaviour?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

In `ViewController.m` set `viewDidAppear`

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [_mainTableView addSubview:refreshControl];
    [_mainTableView sendSubviewToBack:refreshControl];

- (void)handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {

//set your code here 
    [_mainTableView reloadData];
    [_mainTableView layoutIfNeeded];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

Comment: That is basically the same code I am using. The refreshControl's initialization does not seem to be the problem because it is visible when I drag down the tableView. Besides, the same code is working in the fullscreen view. It seems that the refreshControl behaves different because it is placed inside a popover view, at least that is what I am thinking.